# Problems running a module using Python sys library

Tags: python, python-3.x, sys, python-importlib

I'm currently trying to run a module that I previously added to the sys.modules dictionary.

The module insertion is successful but I cannot run it using the following line of code:

```
result = sys.modules["mymodule"].run()
```

Comment: So, what's wrong with importing it the normal way?

Comment: The exercise I'm trying to do says to import it using a "different" way. I think that I could run it with importlib; is that possible?

Comment: Well, it's your exercise. There should be instructions, should they?

Comment: There aren't any instructions and I'm feeling a bit confused. I tried searching online but found nothing